# MacBook white support 64-bit

Tags: snow-leopard, macbook-pro, windows

Need to ask a question about my MacBook White

It's Early 2009 model (http://support.apple.com/kb/SP504)

My question is, will it support:
1. Snow Leopard with 64-bit
2. Windows 7 with 64-bit

Thanks

Comment: Your Mac uses a “Core 2 Duo” processor (see  > About This Mac); it will support 64-bit apps (the Mac OS X kernel usually runs in 32-bit mode on most Macs, but you can still run 64-bit applications on it). There were only a few models of Intel Macs that do not support 64-bit mode. You can identify them based on their “Core Duo” or “Core Solo” processors (most of the non-“late 2006” MacBook, iMac, and Mac mini models). http://www.apple-history.com/ is nice for reviewing old specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Snow Leopard, you never really say if you want 64bit or not.

With Windows, yes, [according to this Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1846), your laptop supports 64bit Windows

Comment: I have this Macbook model (http://www.apple-history.com/?page=gallery&model=mb_early_09&sort=date&performa=off&order=ASC) it's early 2009 one, and I check link that you gave (http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1846), it does not mention my model. Can you explain me how you reached to conclusion that my model will support 64 bit Windows? Thanks for the help

Comment: The Core 2 Duo is a 64 bit processor. You can also see on here they list you can run windows 64 bit (http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/stats/macbook-core-2-duo-2.0-white-13-early-2009-nvidia-specs.html). Lastly, does your machine have 4GB or more RAM installed? If not, I don't even think you would see a difference between 32 and 64 bit OS's.

Answer (score 2):

This model has a 64-bit CPU, and thus can run programs in 64-bit mode in both Leopard and Snow Leopard (note that MacOS doesn't have an overall 32/64-bit switch, it just runs each program in the best mode available).  It will not support booting Snow Leopard's kernel in 64-bit mode (see [Apple's KB article #HT3770](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3770)), but the kernel mode is not particularly important.